# Can an ibeacon (beacon) mimic the close proximity of NFC to send notication?

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, ibeacon, ibeacon-android

Can you use an ibeacon (beacon) to send a notification to a smartphone from within 10 inches or less (25cm or less)?  Can the proximity be even closer like  NFC?  Would you need the scan interval of the beacon to be at 100ms or could you have the scan interval closer to 1 second?

Answer (score 2):

In theory, you can do this by using beacon ranging APIs and measuring the estimated distance to the beacon.  But there are a couple of **practical challenges which will make it less reliable than NFC:**

1. The distance estimate on beacons is based on the RSSI of the bluetooth signal, which has a lot of variation due to noise, multipath and attenuation from obstructions.  These effects are less at close range, but **at 10cm your distance estimate may vary from 0-20cm.**
2. Due to the variation above, distance estimates are typically smoothed out using a 20 second running average of the RSSI.  On Android, this is configurable using the [Android Beacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/), but on iOS `CoreLocation` it is not.  **This means that it will take 20s for the distance estimate to fully converge on 10cm after a mobile device approaches a beacon.**

The scan interval you mention is not configurable on iOS -- ranging updates are locked at 1Hz.  Android is more flexible.  What is more important is the beacon transmission rate, which should be as fast as possible -- at least 10Hz.  This will make distance estimates more reliable because of more statistical samples of RSSI measurements.

Again, issue #2 is the biggest challenge on iOS.  You can avoid it by not using iBeacon APIs and instead using a different beacon standard like [AltBeacon](http://altbeacon.org/), which will allow you to use `CoreBluetooth` APIs instead of `CoreLocation` APIs.  (iOS blocks you from seeing iBeacons with `CoreBluetooth`). This approach, however, requires you to write custom code for the beacon parsing and the distance estimate.